# Downloading Files Simultaneously Using ThreadPool implementation

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, download, threadpool

I'm currently working on a Rust project where I need to download multiple files simultaneously using a thread pool provided by a custom library I'm using.
The library defines a ThreadPool struct that handles creating and managing worker threads.
I'm having some difficulty integrating this thread pool with my download process. I'm using the ThreadPool provided by the library to perform various tasks, and I'd like to use it to download files concurrently as well. However, I'm unsure about how to modify my existing code to achieve this.

My lib.rs file defines the ThreadPool as follows:

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub struct ThreadPool {
workers: Vec<Worker>,
sender: mpsc::Sender<Message>,
}

struct Worker {
 id: usize,
 thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

enum Message {
 NewJob(Job),
 Terminate,
 Panicked,
}

impl ThreadPool {
   pub fn new(num_threads: usize) -> ThreadPool {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));

    let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(num_threads);

    for id in 0..num_threads {
        let receiver = Arc::clone(&receiver);
        let worker = Worker::new(id, receiver);
        workers.push(worker);
    }

    ThreadPool { workers, sender }
  }

pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
{
    let job = Box::new(f);
    self.sender.send(Message::NewJob(job)).unwrap();
}

pub fn join(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let num_threads = self.workers.len();

    for _ in 0..num_threads {
        self.sender.send(Message::Terminate).unwrap();
    }

    let mut panicked = false;

    for worker in &mut self.workers {
        if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
            if let Err(err) = thread.join() {
                eprintln!("Worker {} thread panicked: {:?}", worker.id, err);
                worker.thread = None;
                self.sender.send(Message::Panicked).unwrap();
                panicked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for worker in &self.workers {
        if let Some(_) = &worker.thread {
            return Err(format!("Worker {} thread panicked", worker.id).into());
        }
    }

    if panicked {
        Err("worker threads panicked".into())
    } else {
        Ok(())
      }
     }
    }

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    for worker in &mut self.workers {
        if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
            thread.join().unwrap();
        }
      }
   }
 }

impl Worker {
  fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Message>>>) -> Worker {
    let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

        match message {
            Message::NewJob(job) => {
                job();
            }
            Message::Terminate => {
                break;
            }
            Message::Panicked => {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    Worker {
        id,
        thread: Some(thread),
    }
   }
 }
```

In my main.rs, I have a code block where I want to initiate the download process. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
"download" => {
let mut diff_snapshot: Option<Arc<Mutex<Snapshot>>> =
    Some(Arc::new(Mutex::new(Snapshot::new())));

if let Some(temp_diff_snaphot) = snapshot_received.compare(&local_snapshot) {
    diff_snapshot = Some(Arc::new(Mutex::new(temp_diff_snaphot)));
}

let mut thread_pool2 = ThreadPool::new(num_threads);
let download_file_time = Instant::now();

match diff_snapshot {
    Some(diff_snapshot) => {
        let snapshot = diff_snapshot.lock().unwrap();
        let files = snapshot.files.clone();
        log::info!("We should download {} files", files.len());

        let runtime = Arc::new(Runtime::new().unwrap());
        let file_path_clone_download = file_path.to_string();

        for file in files {
            let full_url = format!("{}{}", file_url_server, file.id);
            let full_path = format!("{}{}", file_path_clone_download, file.path);
            let runtime_clone = Arc::clone(&runtime);
            thread_pool2.execute(move || {
                let url_clone = full_url.clone();
                runtime_clone.block_on(async {
                    let _ = file_transfer::download(&url_clone, &full_path).await;
                });
            });
        }
        thread_pool2.join().unwrap();
    }

    None => {
        log::info!("Nothing to do; the files are the same on both local and server");
    }
}

log::info!(
    "Time of download process : {:?} on {} threads",
    Instant::now() - download_file_time,
    num_threads
);
}
_ => {
log::info!("Invalid choice");
}
```

**Current Outcome**: Currently, the code initiates the download process, but it's not performing concurrent downloads. Instead, it seems to download files sequentially.
**Desired Outcome**: I want to modify the code to leverage the ThreadPool from the library and perform concurrent downloads of multiple files.

Comment: This code should download files in parallel, but it will only download the number of threads the threadpool has in parallel. If you want fully parallel download, spawn more threads or use an async runtime.

Comment: I already use an async runtime provided by Tokio. use tokio::runtime::Runtime;The version is tokio-util = {version="0.7.8", features = ["full"]}

Comment: But you `block_on()`, you don't actually use the async facilities to execute concurrently.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure you're downloading the files at parallel at all. It appears that since you're using the same async runtime, you can only download them serially.

Comment: Async execution should be sufficient here. 1 core of any mainstream (desktop/server) CPU is enough to receive a lot of data data from many different sources (and even store it). Using multiple threads will not make that faster (unless the async system is very inefficient in the first place), but it will certainly make your application harder to maintain (multithreading require synchronizations).

Comment: thank you for responses. Instead of using my own thread pool to execute jobs, I execute tasks in the tokio thread pool using async rust. I replaced threadpool.execute in main.rs with tokio::task::spawn, specifically tokio::spawn with await scenario.